# How to attach current slider image to contact form in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, divi

What I'm trying to achieve is this:

There is an image slider on a page which has a contact (get quote) form.

There are 8 images in the slider.

When someone will fill out the quote form and send it through, I would like to also attach the currently visible image ID (image name, link or any other attribute would work) to the email body.

So when the email comes through to me, it should hopefully say something like:

Name: name
Email: email@email.com
Image: image-1.png OR https://website.com/uploads/image-1.png

The aim of this is because the images I have on display are vastly different in terms of labour and cost.

My main struggle is getting the current visible image in the slider.

Any help would me much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Is it an Ajax form ? If so, you could find the current image with some javascript and add this data to your form?

It could be done by finding the visible image with

```
document.querySelector('.sliderImage:visible').getAttribute('src')
```

And adding it to datas you're sending in Ajax.

If it's a php form, you could add a hidden field and change his value with javascript

Comment: It's not an Ajax form but this is a good place to start, thanks!